# Burninate [bar] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

[bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bar) (33 posts) seems to be used for several different things - mainly, things that should be tagged [progress-bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/progress-bar), but also things like [searchbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/searchbar), [navbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/navbar), [taskbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/taskbar), and [bar-graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bar-graph).  As such, it is ambiguous and probably should be removed.

Comment: I would vote to re-add [tag:foo].

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just went through, re-tagging everything to something sane and downvoting the crap.
(90%+ will be roomba-ed soon).

[image: DIS HAZ BIN BURNINATED]